# How to update obfs4proxy source code?

Tags: relays, bridge, obfsproxy

So I correctly downloaded and build the obfs4proxy source code about a month ago, using the documented

```
go get git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/obfs4proxy
```

Now how do I update my local copy of the source to pick up changes made since my initial download? I see that some files in the repository have change, but rerunning the "go get" command doesn't to fetch the changes.

Any advice on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I didn't change anything important as long as you are using a relatively recent version (0.0.3 was tagged on Oct 1.), and the changes since then are only to the unit tests.

`go get -u [URL]` will update dependencies and re-download everything, but the build is broken right now due to the Go developers messing with `go.crypto` (and probably `go.net`) in a way that broke backward compatibility (by moving the repo, and changing `import` locations).

The fixes for that are relatively straight forward, but I need to figure out how to deal with this for the Debian binary packages, so it'll be when I get to it.  Sorry.  The last know good `go.crypto` hg revision is `231:7ad4bae3f467` in case you actually do want to try to build this yourself at the moment.